# Attaching Image in the body of mail in C#

Tags: c#, image, email, smtp

How can I attach an image in the body content . I have written the below code

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
string UserName = "xyz@someorg.com";
string Password = "my password";
message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("toaddress@toadddress.com"));
message.From = new  System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("fromaddress@fromaddress.com");              
message.Subject = "test subject";
message.Body = "<img src=@'C:\\Sunset.jpg'/>";                
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
 smtpClient.Host = "hostname";
 smtpClient.Port = 25;
 smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
 smtpClient.Send(message);
```

The code is fine as I am receiving the message also but the image is coming as [X] inside the body and not as the image. 
How to solve this? The path is correct?

Comment: Thanks I solved message.Body = "<img src='C:\\Sunset.jpg'/>";

Comment: No you didn't.  The odds that the recipient has that file stored in the root directory are zero.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unless the email is only ever sent to the OP! ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
    string attachmentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\test.png";
    Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
    inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
    inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    inline.ContentId = contentID;
    inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
    inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);

    message.Attachments.Add(inline);
```

---

reference: [**Send an Email in C# with Inline attachments**](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx)

Comment: Oh... this approach seems even better.

Comment: For anybody looking at this solution in the future, in order to make it work, I had to add the following image tag in my code (My ContendId is "Screenshot"): `message.Body = "<img src=\"cid:Screenshot\" alt=\"\" />";`

Comment: The `cid` link doesn't seem to work for Outlook on Android, but works for Outlook on Windows and Samsung Email. Got It working by `AlternateView` and `LinkedResource` instead, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126266/2441442). Not sure what the differnce is.

Answer (score 1):

Use so called `LinkedResource`. [Here](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.4.aspx) you can find how-to. Have done that successfully.

If tutorial does not help, don't be shy and ask for clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace ItsTrulyFree
{
    public partial class demo_mail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    enter code here
        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                // File Upload path
                String FileName = fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; 


                string mailbody = txtBody.Text + "<br/><img src=cid:companylogo>";

            //LinkedResource LinkedImage = new LinkedResource(FileName);
                     //HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles");
            LinkedResource LinkedImage = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~//" + FileName), "image/jpg");
                LinkedImage.ContentId = "MyPic";
                //Added the patch for Thunderbird as suggested by Jorge
                LinkedImage.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailbody+
                  " <img src=cid:MyPic>",
                  null, "text/html");

                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(LinkedImage);
                Msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                Msg = null;
                Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
            }
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            //}
        }

}
```