# Generate email with inline image

Tags: image, email, email-attachments

I am trying to generate an email text with an image inserted in it. I understand I should use the syntax `<img src="cid:image-id" />` and add the image as attachment. I tried to do that and the result is the following :

```
--===============6239034322813840804==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============6051774682785554910=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============6051774682785554910==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

my email in base64 with text only

--===============6051774682785554910==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

my email in base64 with html
...
<img src="cid:my-image.png" alt="My Image">
...

--===============6051774682785554910==--
--===============6239034322813840804==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: image/png; name="badge-img.png"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="badge-img.png"
Content-ID: <badge-img.png>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBI
...
```

When sent, the image is in attachment (can open it, valid image). But in the displayed email content, I only see the alt text "My Image", not the image.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the problem. I have to use [multipart/related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Related) content type and change the structure. I have currently something like this

```
<email>
    <part1 content-type=multipart/alternative>
        <subpart1>plain text</subpart1>
        <subpart2>html text</subpart2>
    </part1>
    <part2>
        attachments
    </part2>
</email>
```

and should have something like

```
<email>
    <part content-type=multipart/alternative>
        <subpart1>plain text</subpart1>
        <subpart2 content-type=multipart/related>
            <subsubpart1>html text</subsubpart1>
            <subsubpart2>attachments</subsubpart2>
        </subpart2>
    </part>
</email>
```

I still have to change my code to adapt but it seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's the language you using? In C# you need try something like that:

[sending mail along with embedded image using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net)

or

[Attaching Image in the body of mail in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317012/attaching-image-in-the-body-of-mail-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thank you but I don't think it's related to the programming language (and I use python) but to the generated email structure.

Comment: Ok, but without the code we can't see how the structure was created.