# Send inline image in email

Tags: c#, image, email, smtp, inline

Having an issue sending an image via email as an embedded image in the body.
The image file shows as an attachment which is ok but the inline image portion just shows as a red x.

Here is what I have so far

```
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(filePath);
inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
Attachment att = new Attachment(filePath);
att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
mail.From = from_email;
mail.To.Add(data.email);
mail.Subject = "Client: " + data.client_id + " Has Sent You A Screenshot";
mail.Body = String.Format(
    "<h3>Client: " + data.client_id + " Has Sent You A Screenshot</h3>" +
    @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId);

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Comment: You're not actually appending the LinkedResource to the mail object; instead, you're creating it but then attaching a separate Attachment object.

Comment: The only problem with this code is that your string.Format is referencing `inline.ContentId`, when it should actually be `att.ContentId`. `inline` isn't required at all. I prefer your question to all the answers, as you really don't need to use an `AlternateView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# sending mails with images inline using SmtpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212838/c-sharp-sending-mails-with-images-inline-using-smtpclient)

Comment: My image is being attached as bin file extension. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check this link.  it has ready to use method for multiple inline  attachment as well as for general attachment  for pdf/excel files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665280/add-multiple-images-in-the-email-body-inlineusing-c-sharp-windows-application/49329461#49329461

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this

```
 string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=\"cid:filename\"></body></html>";
 AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
    (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

 LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("filename.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
 inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

 Attachment att = new Attachment(filePath);
 att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

 mail.From = from_email;
 mail.To.Add(data.email);
 mail.Subject = "Client: " + data.client_id + " Has Sent You A Screenshot";
 mail.Body = String.Format(
            "<h3>Client: " + data.client_id + " Has Sent You A Screenshot</h3>" +
            @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", att.ContentId);

 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
 mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, use the below code from @T30, and keep in mind when you add Alternate View to MailMessage that view will be the body of your email and you DONT need to fill the Body property.

Comment: @Eric: there was a small issue in this code. in the mail.body just use att.ContentId instead of inline.ContentId

Answer (score 196):

Some minimal c# code to embed an image, can be:

```
MailMessage mailWithImg = GetMailWithImg();
MySMTPClient.Send(mailWithImg); //* Set up your SMTPClient before!

private MailMessage GetMailWithImg() {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(GetEmbeddedImage("c:/image.png"));
    mail.From = new MailAddress("yourAddress@yourDomain");
    mail.To.Add("recipient@hisDomain");
    mail.Subject = "yourSubject";
    return mail;
}

private AlternateView GetEmbeddedImage(String filePath) {
    LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(filePath);
    res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>";
    AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
    return alternateView;
}
```

Comment: I had to add a mime type to the `LinkedResource` to make it work in Hotmail/Outlook.com's web client.  FWIW, I tried this as well as @Microsoft DN and this worked better.

Comment: For me it works, but I had to add the ContentType: 
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

Comment: Small comment: no need to call `NewGuid()`, the `AttachmentBase` class 
(which `LinkedResource` inherits from) already creates it if needed.

Comment: Add to the LinkedResource the ContentType "image/bmp" for not receiving the image as a attached file.

Comment: Do you have to release anything after the email is sent if referencing the same res over and over again?

Comment: @WilliamHumphries I think the garbage collector already handles this.

Comment: encoding of the html AlternateView should be defined to prevent issues with special characters in various mail clients. e.g. `AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);`

Answer (score 15):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Themessage = @"<html>
                          <body>
                            <table width=""100%"">
                            <tr>
                                <td style=""font-style:arial; color:maroon; font-weight:bold"">
                               Hi! <br>
                                <img src=cid:myImageID>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            </body>
                            </html>";
        sendHtmlEmail("from@gmail.com", "tomailaccount", Themessage, "Scoutfoto", "Test HTML Email", "smtp.gmail.com", 25);
    }

    protected void sendHtmlEmail(string from_Email, string to_Email, string body, string           from_Name, string Subject, string SMTP_IP, Int32 SMTP_Server_Port)
    {
        //create an instance of new mail message
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //set the HTML format to true
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //create Alrternative HTML view
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");

        //Add Image
        LinkedResource theEmailImage = new LinkedResource("E:\\IMG_3332.jpg");
        theEmailImage.ContentId = "myImageID";

        //Add the Image to the Alternate view
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);

        //Add view to the Email Message
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        //set the "from email" address and specify a friendly 'from' name
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from_Email, from_Name);

        //set the "to" email address
        mail.To.Add(to_Email);

        //set the Email subject
        mail.Subject = Subject;

        //set the SMTP info
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fromEmail@gmail.com", "fromEmail password");
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = cred;
        //send the email
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the comments above, I have the following additional comments:

- Do not mix Attachments and AlternativeView, use one or the other. If you mix them, the inline attachments will be rendered as unknown downloads.
- While Outlook and Google allow standard HTML-style `"cid:att-001"` this does **NOT** work on iPhone (late 2016 patch level), rather use pure alpha numeric `"cid:att-001" -> "cid:att001"`

As an aside: Outlook (even Office 2015) rendering (still the clear majority for business users) requires the use of TABLE TR TD style HTML, as it does not fully support the HTML box model.

Comment: Great, I am impressed from your research.

Comment: This is still the case in 2020, just had to replace all LinkedResource/AlternativeView code with Attachment code because I also needed file attachments, and this post seems to be the only thing on the entire internet that mentions that that won't work

Answer (score 8):

An even more minimalistic example:

```
var linkedResource = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Image.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

// My mail provider would not accept an email with only an image, adding hello so that the content looks less suspicious.
var htmlBody = $"hello<img src=\"cid:{linkedResource.ContentId}\"/>";
var alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);

var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("youremail@host.com"),
    To = { "recipient@host.com" },
    Subject = "yourSubject",
    AlternateViews = { alternateView }
};

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This.

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Themessage = @"<html>
                              <body>
                                <table width=""100%"">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style=""font-style:arial; color:maroon; font-weight:bold"">
                                   Hi! <br>
                                    <img src=cid:myImageID>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                                </body>
                                </html>";
            sendHtmlEmail("from@gmail.com", "tomailaccount", Themessage, "Scoutfoto", "Test HTML Email", "smtp.gmail.com", 25);
        }
```

---

```
protected void sendHtmlEmail(string from_Email, string to_Email, string body, string from_Name, string Subject, string SMTP_IP, Int32 SMTP_Server_Port)
        {
            //create an instance of new mail message
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            //set the HTML format to true
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //create Alrternative HTML view
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");

            //Add Image
            LinkedResource theEmailImage = new LinkedResource("E:\\IMG_3332.jpg");
            theEmailImage.ContentId = "myImageID";

            //Add the Image to the Alternate view
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(theEmailImage);

            //Add view to the Email Message
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            //set the "from email" address and specify a friendly 'from' name
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from_Email, from_Name);

            //set the "to" email address
            mail.To.Add(to_Email);

            //set the Email subject
            mail.Subject = Subject;

            //set the SMTP info
            System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fromEmail@gmail.com", "fromEmail password");
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = cred;
            //send the email
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Example on how to embed multiple images into an HTML email.  Note, if you try to use newer HTML elements such as flexbox you will have trouble. If you use a simple table it will work.  When I tried with flexbox the styling wasn't recognized.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var html = File.ReadAllText("c:\test.html");
    var altView = GetAlternateView(html);
    SendEmail(new List<MailRecipients> {new MailAddress(someone@email.com)}, "Hello!", "Images in Email Test!", true, altView);
}


public static bool SendEmail(List<MailAddress> recipients, string body, string subject, bool html, AlternateView view, MailPriority priority = MailPriority.Normal)
{
   try
   {
       MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
       SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
       message.From = new MailAddress(ConfigLookup.GetStringValue(ConfigNames.EmailFrom));
       recipients.ForEach(r => message.To.Add(new MailAddress(r.Address)));
       message.Subject = subject;
       message.IsBodyHtml = html;
       message.AlternateViews.Add(view);
       message.Priority = priority;
       smtp.Port = 25;
       smtp.Host = youremailhost;
       smtp.EnableSsl = yes;
       smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
       smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
       smtp.Send(message);
       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       return false;
   }
}    
           
private AlternateView GetAlternateView(string html)
{
    var logoPath = ConfigLookup.GetStringValue(ConfigNames.LogoPath);
    LinkedResource logoResource = new LinkedResource(logoPath);
    
    // ContentID must match the 'cid:contentId' in the html
    logoResource.ContentId = "logo";
    
    // Without a Mime type the images will show up as attached .bin files
    logoResource.ContentType = new ContentType("image/png");
    logoResource.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

    var heroPath = ConfigLookup.GetStringValue(ConfigNames.HeroPath);
    LinkedResource heroResource = new LinkedResource(heroPath);
    
    // ContentID must match the 'cid:contentId' in the html
    heroResource.ContentId = "hero";
    
    // Without a Mime type the images will show up as attached .bin files
    heroResource.ContentType = new ContentType("image/png");
    heroResource.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
                        
    AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(logoResource);
    alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(heroResource);
    return alternateView;
}
```

In your Html, the main thing that links up the images to the LinkedResource is the 'cid:contentId' must match:

```
<a href="https://somesite.com" target="_blank" style="color:#033254;">
    <img src="cid:logo" width="218" alt="Company logo" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
</a>
<a href="https://somesite.com" target="_blank" style="color:#033254;">
    <img src="cid:hero" width="218" alt="Company hero" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
</a>
```

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Shipping Confirmation from Products Company</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;word-spacing:normal;">
        <div role="article" aria-roledescription="email" lang="en" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#ffffff;">
            <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="outer" style="width:96%;max-width:660px;margin:20px auto;background-color:#ffffff;">
                            <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr style="background-color:rgb(35, 68, 107);">
                                    <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0;">
                                        <a href="https://yahoo.com" target="_blank" style="color:#033254;">
                                        <img src="cid:logo" width="218" alt="Products Company logo" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;;">
                                    <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0;">
                                        <a href="https://yahoo.com" target="_blank" style="color:#033254;">
                                        <img src="cid:hero" width="400" alt="Products Company hero" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background-color:rgb(35, 68, 107);">
                                    <td style="padding:32px; text-align:center;">
                                        <h1 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:16px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:30px;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
                                            Shipping Confirmation
                                        </h1>
                                        <hr style="border:0;background-color:rgb(35, 68, 107);border-bottom:.5px solid #ffffff;width:66%;"/>
                                        <h3 style="margin:16px 0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">Order# {0}</h3>
                                        <h3 style="margin:16px 0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">{1}</h3>
                                        <p style="margin:24px 0 8px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:.5px;color:#ffffff;">Thank you for your order!</p>
                                        <p style="margin:8px 0 8px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:.5px;color:#ffffff;">Good news! It's on its way.</p>
                                        <p style="margin:8px 0 8px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:.5px;color:#ffffff;">You can find the shipping details below.</p>
                                        <h3 style="margin:16px 0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
                                            <a style="color:#ffffff;" href="https://www.ups.com/mobile/track?trackingNumber={2}">
                                            [Track my package!]
                                            </a>
                                        </h3>
                                        <p style="margin:32px 0 8px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:.5px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">Please contact Customer Service if you have any questions.</p>
                                        <p style="margin:8px 0 8px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:.5px;color:#ffffff;">Customer Service:
                                            <a style="color:#ffffff;" href="tel:18003665412">1-800-888-8888</a> ext. 8888
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The other solution is attaching the image as attachment and then referencing it html code using cid.
HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img width=100 height=100 id=""1"" src=""cid:Logo.jpg"">
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
email.Subject = "Email with Image";
email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html);
email.ToRecipients.Add("abc@xyz.com");
string file = @"C:\Users\acv\Pictures\Logo.jpg";
email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Logo.jpg", file);
email.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
email.Attachments[0].ContentId = "Logo.jpg";
email.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Answer (score 2):

We all have our preferred coding styles. This is what I did:

```
var pictures = new[]
{
    new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), type = "image/jpeg", tag = "justme", path = @"C:\Pictures\JustMe.jpg" },
    new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), type = "image/jpeg", tag = "justme-bw", path = @"C:\Pictures\JustMe-BW.jpg" }
}.ToList();

var content = $@"
<style type=""text/css"">
    body {{ font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; }}
</style>
<body>
<h4>{DateTime.Now:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt}</h4>
<p>Some pictures</p>
<div>
    <p>Color Picture</p>
    <img src=cid:{{justme}} />
</div>
<div>
    <p>Black and White Picture</p>
    <img src=cid:{{justme-bw}} />
</div>
<div>
    <p>Color Picture repeated</p>
    <img src=cid:{{justme}} />
</div>
</body>
";

// Update content with picture guid
pictures.ForEach(p => content = content.Replace($"{{{p.tag}}}", $"{p.id}"));
// Create Alternate View
var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
// Add the resources
pictures.ForEach(p => view.LinkedResources.Add(new LinkedResource(p.path, p.type) { ContentId = p.id.ToString() }));

using (var client = new SmtpClient()) // Set properties as needed or use config file
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Subject = "Picture Email",
    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
})
{
    message.AlternateViews.Add(view);
    message.From = new MailAddress("me@me.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@you.com"));
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the complete code below to display images in Gmail,Thunderbird and other email clients :

```
MailMessage mailWithImg = getMailWithImg();
MySMTPClient.Send(mailWithImg); //* Set up your SMTPClient before!

private MailMessage getMailWithImg()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(getEmbeddedImage("c:/image.png"));
    mail.From = new MailAddress("yourAddress@yourDomain");
    mail.To.Add("recipient@hisDomain");
    mail.Subject = "yourSubject";
    return mail;
}
private AlternateView getEmbeddedImage(String filePath)
 {
    // below line was corrected to include the mediatype so it displays in all 
    // mail clients. previous solution only displays in Gmail the inline images 
    LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);  
    res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>";
    AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody,  
     null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
    return alternateView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the LinkedResource into an AlternateView

```
AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<h3>Client: " + data.client_id + " Has Sent You A Screenshot</h3>" +
                @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", null, "text/html");
alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(inline);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    //set the addresses
    mail.From = new MailAddress("userid@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("userid@gmail.com");

    //set the content
    mail.Subject = "Sucessfully Sent the HTML and Content of mail";

    //first we create the Plain Text part
    string plainText = "Non-HTML Plain Text Message for Non-HTML enable mode";
    AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainText, null, "text/plain");
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"E:\HTMLPage.htm");
    string[] address = new string[30];
    string finalHtml = "";
    var i = -1;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        { // The node is an element.
            if (reader.AttributeCount <= 1)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "img")
                {
                    finalHtml += "<" + reader.Name;
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "src")
                        {
                            i++;
                            address[i] = reader.Value;
                            address[i] = address[i].Remove(0, 8);
                            finalHtml += " " + reader.Name + "=" + "cid:chartlogo" + i.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            finalHtml += " " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'";
                        }
                    }
                    finalHtml += ">";
                }
                else
                {
                    finalHtml += "<" + reader.Name;
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        finalHtml += " " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'";
                    }
                    finalHtml += ">";
                }
            }

        }
        else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        { //Display the text in each element.
            finalHtml += reader.Value;
        }
        else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            //Display the end of the element.
            finalHtml += "</" + reader.Name;
            finalHtml += ">";
        }

    }

    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(finalHtml, null, "text/html");
    LinkedResource[] logo = new LinkedResource[i + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        logo[j] = new LinkedResource(address[j]);
        logo[j].ContentId = "chartlogo" + j;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo[j]);
    }
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        "userid@gmail.com", "Password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    Console.WriteLine();
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> sending 2 images vb.net code convert for C# online converter.

```
Public Function SendEmail(Optional ByVal p_AsHTML As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal p_themEmail As String = "") As Boolean
            Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient ''("FMSERVER.FMINNOVATIONS.COM.AU")
            'Dim fromAddress As MailAddress = New MailAddress(Me.FromEmail, "WSMenterprise")
            'Dim toAddress As MailAddress
            Try
                Dim aMessage As New MailMessage()
                '(New MailAddress(Me.FromEmail, "WSMenterprise"), New MailAddress(anAdd))
                If _fromAddress IsNot Nothing Then
                    If _fromName IsNot Nothing Then
                        aMessage.From = New MailAddress(_fromAddress, _fromName)
                    Else
                        aMessage.From = New MailAddress(_fromAddress)
                    End If
                End If
                For Each anAdd As String In _To
                    aMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(anAdd))
                Next
                For Each cc As String In _CC
                    aMessage.CC.Add(New MailAddress(cc))
                Next
                For Each bcc As String In _BCC
                    aMessage.Bcc.Add(New MailAddress(bcc))
                Next
                aMessage.Subject = _Subject
                aMessage.IsBodyHtml = p_AsHTML

                If _EmailLogo Is Nothing Then
                    aMessage.Body = _Body
                Else
                    If p_themEmail.ToString().ToLower.Contains("dexus") Then

                       Dim htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), Nothing, "text/html")
                        Dim logo As New LinkedResource(_EmailLogo)
                        logo.ContentId = "Dexuslogo1"
                        Dim logo1 As New LinkedResource(_EmailLogo1)
                        logo1.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2"
                        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo)
                        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo1)
                        aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)

                    Else

                        Dim htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), Nothing, "text/html")
                        Dim logo As New LinkedResource(_EmailLogo)
                        logo.ContentId = "companylogo"
                        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo)
                        aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
                    End If
                End If

                For Each anAttach As Attachment In _Attachments
                    aMessage.Attachments.Add(anAttach)
                Next

                If _ReplyTo IsNot Nothing Then aMessage.ReplyToList.Add(New MailAddress(_ReplyTo))
                client.Host = "smtpi.cbre.com.au"
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                client.Send(aMessage)
            Catch exRecipUnk As SmtpFailedRecipientException
                Return False
            Catch exSmtp As SmtpException
                ''exSmtp.StatusCode
                Return False
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try
            Return True
        End Function
    If p_Gmap_code = "DE" Then
                Dim p_Theme As New Theme("Dexus")
                Dim passwordlink As String = ""
                Dim DexuslogoImage1 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images\Dexus_Notice_Logo.png")
                Dim DexuslogoImage2 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images\DexusTenantNotice.png")

                passwordlink = "<a href='" + p_Theme.TenantLoginPage + "?accesstype=email&te=" + a.Encrypt(p_TenantEmail) + "' target='_blank'>here.</a><br/>"
                bodys += "<div align='Center'><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr style='height:50px;'><td width='623px' ></td><td valign='top' width='180'><p align='right'><a href='http://www.dexus.com/'><img border='0' height='50' src=cid:Dexuslogo1 width='174' alt=''/></a></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:25px;'></td></tr> <tr><td width='623px'><p align='left' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;'><strong> Your Dexus Response Password is about to expire</strong></p></td>"
                bodys += " <td width='180'><p align='right' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " </p>"
                bodys += "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:30px;'>  </td></tr> <tr>  <td colspan='2' width='803' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'>"
                bodys += "<p>" + wishes + " " + p_TenantName.Trim().ToString() + "</p>"
                bodys += "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:25px;'></td> </tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'>"
                bodys += "Your Dexus Response password is about to expire in " + p_remaindays.ToString() + " days.<br /><br /> To reset your password and update your details, please click " + passwordlink.ToString() + "<br /><br />Please note that if you do not update your password by " + p_date + ",then your account will be set to inactive and you will not be able to access Dexus Response.</br></br>Please contact Dexus Response if you require assistance in accessing the portal.</p></td>" 'edit
                bodys += " </tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:30px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803'><table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td width='802' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'><p><strong>Dexus Response</strong></p></td></tr><tr><td width='802' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'><p><a href='mailto:property.services@dexusfm.com'>property.services@dexusfm.com</a> <strong>|</strong> 1300 339 870 <strong>|</strong> <a href='https://response.dexus.com/'>response.dexus.com</a></p></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:15px;'></td></tr><tr> <td colspan='2' width='803'><p> </p><p><a href='https://response.dexus.com/' border='0' target='_blank'><img border='0' height='133'"
                bodys += "src=cid:Dexuslogo2 alt='' width='800' /></a></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:10px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;'><p><a href='http://www.dexus.com/who-we-are/terms-and-conditions' style=' color:#000000;'>Terms and Conditions</a><strong> | </strong><a href='http://www.dexus.com/who-we-are/privacy-policy' style=' color:#000000;'> Privacy Policy</a></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:40px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803'><p></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:10px;'></td></tr><tr></tr><tr><td colspan='2' width='803' style='height:20px;'></td></tr></table></div>"

                email = New Common.Email(emailHeading, bodys, p_Theme.EmailFrom, DexuslogoImage1, DexuslogoImage2)
                email.ToEmail = p_TenantEmail
                email.SendEmail(True, p_Theme.EmailFrom)
```