# Email with signature logo fetched from Resource File

Tags: c#, image, email, embedded-resource

I am writing a Windows service which will trigger emails. The functionality can also be triggered from a Windows application using the same piece of code.

The emails which we trigger should be having a signature with a logo, which is in a resource file. The emails are getting triggered fine but the image is not showing up, but the placeholder for image is. This is the code I am using:

```cs
try
{
    Bitmap imgAttachment = Project.Shared.Properties.Resources.Image1;
    using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ContentType type = new ContentType()
        {
            MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg,
            Name = "attachment"
        };
        imgAttachment.Save(mstream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Attachment sigAttachment = new Attachment(mstream, type);
        string ContentId = "imagelogo";
        sigAttachment.ContentId = ContentId;
        sigAttachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        sigAttachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
        message.Attachments.Add(sigAttachment);

        message.Body = Body + "<htm><body> <br/><br/><table border='0' cellpadding='0'     
            cellspacing='0' width='1000'>  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>  <tr>    <td 
            rowspan='8' valign='top' align='left'><img alt = 'Logo' src=\"cid:" + 
            ContentId + "\"></td> <td width='1000' height='46' valign='top'> " + 
            SignatureLine1 + " </td>  </tr> <tr> " + SignatureLine2 + " </tr> <tr> " + 
            SignatureLine3 + " </tr> <tr> " + SignatureLine4 + " </tr> </table> 
            </body></html>";
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
catch {}
```

[image: 1]

Can some one help me with this? Am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect there's a slight difference between attachments and embedded resources, and this may be considered a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email

Comment: I did try that as well, but I think my problem is a bit different as even the post you mentioned, gave the same output. (Refer attachment). The Image was not picked up fine.

Comment: What if you set mstream.Position to 0 after saving the image?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not generating the correct MIME structure. The HTML body and the image attachment need to be part of a multipart/related and the code you are writing probably creates a multipart/mixed (I haven't actually tested your code, but having dug around in Mono's System.Net.Mail implementation, it seems your code would generate a multipart/mixed and not a multipart/related, which is what you want).

I don't have a whole lot of experience with System.Net.Mail (it sucks so I wrote my own library), but what you need to do is use an `AlternateView` for the HTML message body and add the image as a `LinkedResource` to that `AlternateView` (see the `AlternateView.LinkedResources` property).