# Lotus notes cannot render css in HTML email where using image as linked source

Tags: c#, email, base64, lotus

My colleague has developed an application that sends an html email showing an enclosed picture.  The program code is something like the code in [Send inline image in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email).

The email looks fine when there is no enclosed image but when an image is enclosed and displayed from linked source, all the css is broken.

[image: Expected output]
[image: Actual Output]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use base64 string:

```
imgstring = "<IMG SRC='data:image/" + image.file_ext.Replace(".", "").Trim () +
            ";base64," + CreateBase64Image(imageFullPath) +
            "' NAME='image' ALIGN=BOTTOM WIDTH=298 HEIGHT=172 BORDER=0>";

body = body.Replace("*replaceme*", imgstring );

private string CreateBase64Image(String path)
{
    byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
    return base64ImageRepresentation;
}
```