# How to add images from resources folder as attachment and embed into outlook mail body in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have a couple of images stored in visual studio project Resources folder, and I have to load them and display on the outlook mail body. Here it is the code:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.MyImage);
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Byte[] ba = (Byte[])ic.ConvertTo(b, typeof(Byte[]));
MemoryStream logo = new MemoryStream(ba);

LinkedResource companyImage = new LinkedResource(logo);
companyImage.ContentId = "companyLogo";
mailitem.HTMLBody += "<img src=\"cid:companyLogo\">";
```

However, it cannot display on the mail body but a ‘empty box with red x’. Can you  give me some ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create an attachment and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

Your HTML body (`MailItem.HTMLBody` property) would then need to reference that image attachment through the cid:

```
<img src="cid:xyz">
```

where `xyz` is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

Look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

```
attachment = mailitem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg");
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1");
mailitem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>";
```

Comment: yes, thanks mate, this is what i did before. It can load the image from my local path directory, but it went wrong if i deploy the application. So i think those images should be stored in application resources so that i can get it from my application directly rather than obtaining it from local path.

Comment: Outlook Object Model only allows to add by-value attachments from files. You can extract the image from a resource to a temporary folder, add the attachment, delete the file.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this.

```
string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src=\"cid:filename\"></body></html>";
 AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
    (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

var fileName = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)),
    fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.Pic);

 LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(path, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg); //Jpeg or something
 inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

 Attachment att = new Attachment(filePath);
 att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

 mail.From = from_email;
 mail.To.Add(data.email);
 mail.Subject = "Here is your subject;
 mail.Body = String.Format(
            "Here is the previous HTML Body" +
            @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId);

 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
 mail.Attachments.Add(att);
```

1. No need to change your picture to memory stream
2. For easy use, please do your content of e-mail to be HTML
3. You can find in the code above

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email) too

Comment: Thanks mate. Actually i prefer to load the image from application resources rather than some local directory. Do you know is there any way i can directory insert the image from "Resources" file to the mail body?

Comment: I added additional code to set your "resource picture" in designated server directory. Don't use memory stream, just use the path (in LinkedResource)