# Adding <img> HTML tag to C# String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, smtp

I'm trying to email an image via Code behind but I can't get it to work. Basically trying to send the  tag with a src so that it will display it in the email I sent:

**Code behind**

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("mail-master@website.com", email);
mm.Subject = "Beta Signup";
string body = "<img src=\"\"http://popl.mpi-sws.org/2015/logos/google.png\"\" />";
mm.Body = body;
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail-master@website.com", "pass@123");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

However this doesn't send the image and I can't see the image showing up in the email I receive

```
string body = "<img src=\"\"http://popl.mpi-sws.org/2015/logos/google.png\"\" />";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send inline image in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including two quotes to enclose the `src` attribute value.

```
"<img src=\"\"http://popl.mpi-sws.org/2015/logos/google.png\"\" />";
```

This will result in invalid HTML:

```
<img src=""http://popl.mpi-sws.org/2015/logos/google.png"" />
```

Try replacing with:

```
string body = "<img src=\"http://popl.mpi-sws.org/2015/logos/google.png\" />";
```