# Refer local disk image in C# html string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, dinktopdf

I am generating a pdf document using DinkToPdf and need to embed an image (present in the release folder) using img tag.

I followed this SO Post :
[Adding <img> HTML tag to C# String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665354/adding-img-html-tag-to-c-sharp-string)

But it only works for internet URLs and not for local disk images

What I tried is
var HTML = @"<img src=""/myimage.png""/>"

But no image is displayed once the PDF is generated. But works fine if the path is an internet URL

How can I solve this?

[Edit to clarify the question]
The image resides in the server and this needs to be embedded in the first page of the document

Comment: I dont think pdf can read data from disk. This is security horror if can.

Comment: @daremachine Probably I presented the question wrong. The image resides in the server and I just want to embed it in the pdf document

Comment: check this https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/27

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify full path like this if you have your image in folder \wwwroot\Documents\ImgName.jpg

```
<img src="https://localhost:50001/Documents/ImgName.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Full path is not needed. Make sure your relative path is correct.

<img src=""/myimage.png""/>"
**Does the image resides on same executing environment?**

If not use **~** to go back a directory. Image cannot exist on different project. It should be same as executing project.

A screenshot of folder structure would be helpful.