# Image won't be sent in Email with this technique

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-email

I'm looking to make my email "parameter-able" so it's easier to work with format and do something that looks professional.

I have this folder :

[image]

This is the content of the Message.htm :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style='color:grey; font-size:15px;'>
    <font face='Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'>

    <div style='position:absolute; height:100px; width:600px; padding:30px;'>
        <img src='logo.png' />
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div style='background-color: #ece8d4; width:600px; height:200px; padding:30px; margin-top:30px;'>

        <p>Please click the link below to login and get started.</p>
        <p>
            Username: {0}<br>
            Password: {1}<br>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>Now get lost... cause it's just a test</p>
    </div>
    </font>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in my controller, simply send it using this c# :

```
 string body;
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("\\Email\\Message.htm") ))
 {
     body = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }


 string username = "anto";
 string password = "RandomNumber";

 string messageBody = string.Format(body, username, password);

 EnvoieCourriel("pelletier_antoine@hotmail.com", messageBody, restOfTheParams);
```

Emial is sent correctly. The problem ? `<img src='logo.png' />` is never showing. I tried a LOT of weird codes. Not been close to success yet...

EDIT :

I want the Image to be sent INSIDE the email, as inline content.

Comment: Did you expect the receiver of your email to see the logo.png file on your server?

Comment: you need to embed the image in email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email

Comment: @urlreader It's seems like it's the good way to go, even though i can't quite figure how to use this `LinkedResource ` thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `HTML` to have a full path in the `img` tag:

```
      <html>
 <head></head>
 <body style='color:grey; font-size:15px;'>
     <font face='Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'>

     <div style='position:absolute; height:100px; width:600px; padding:30px;'>
         <img src='http://somepath.com/images/logo.png' />
     </div>

     <br />
     <br />

     <div style='background-color: #ece8d4; width:600px; height:200px; padding:30px; margin-top:30px;'>

         <p>Please click the link below to login and get started.</p>
         <p>
             Username: {0}<br>
             Password: {1}<br>
         </p>
         <br />
         <p>Now get lost... cause it's just a test</p>
     </div>
     </font>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Otherwise the receiver will never see that image.

Comment: Is there a way to send that image within the mail ? When i insert an image in an email manually, i kind of doubt there is any path to a server

Comment: @AntoinePelletier You just need a complete path to the image online.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I asked for in the beginning, but I MUST admit it works. Simple solutions are sometimes better.