# Am having issue in loading images in gmail .I have created a template from visual studio. but the images are not loading properly

Tags: visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw5sq.png)

I have sent the image source but the images are not loading properly .i having issue in sending the source image .i have sent my localhost in site root and the image source

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *how* are you sending your email with Visual Studio. But for what can be seen in your image, you are not being able to show images in the email body. Maybe [this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18358534/8817027)