# Render SVG in Email body using SendGrid C#

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

I have to place a simple image along with hyperlink inside email body. To send email I am using SendGrid API.

My C# code:

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(EmailDeliveryModel model) {
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    var client = new SendGridClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CommonObject.SendGridKey]);
    var msg = new SendGridMessage();
    msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(model.SourceEmail));
    var recipients = new List();
    //multiple recipients
    foreach(string emailAddress in model.DestinationEmail.Trim(',').Split(',')) {
        recipients.Add(new EmailAddress(emailAddress.Trim()));
    }
    msg.AddTos(recipients);
    msg.SetSubject(model.Subject);
    if (model.ContentType.Equals(CommonObject.ContHTML, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, model.EmailContent + "\n \n \n \n \n");
    } else {
        msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, model.EmailContent + "\n \n \n \n \n");
    }
    var sendGridresponse = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    if (sendGridresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted) {
        response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Inside EmailContent I am injecting html content along with SVG, But SVG is not rendering inside email. But if I am trying the same html in browser it works.

How to send image along with hyper link inside email body?

Comment: HTML which I am injecting: <!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table><tbody><tr><td align='left'><div id="myDIV"><svg 
 SVG_CONTENT</svg></div><label style='font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto-Regular;font-weight:normal;color:#676767;'></td><td align='left'><p><a href = 'SOME_URL'>SOMETEXT</a></p></label></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>

Comment: SVG support in mail clients is variable, Gmail does not support it for example, are you sure its worth doing?

Comment: Basically I need image in email body, if not using SVG then is ther any other way to do it.

Comment: SmtpClient supports inline attachments E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email

Comment: Using SendGrid Only.

Comment: SVG is XML format and may be very large.  XML is not exactly the same as Html.  I would convert the SVG to 64 bit string using System : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: I tried by encoding still its not working