# How to add Image or logo to Email body c# api?

Tags: c#, gmail

I've added img tag to mail body. But it is not display.
Please help me.

My code:

```
string PathLogo = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/Asset/logosinhan.png");
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(PathLogo);
logo.ContentId = "shinhanlogo";
string imgSrc = "<img src=cid:shinhanlogo/>";
emailInfo.Content = emailInfo.Content.Replace("$Logo", imgSrc)
```

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email

Comment: Use dev tool of browser to see if the img path is as expected.