How to add images to email?
In my e-commerce application (Blazor Server, Blazor WASM, Asp.Net Core API), I am sending an order confirmation email from API to the customer. I am using a html template for this e-mail. I couldn't manage to display the logo and ordered product images in the e-mail.
Here is the html template:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Email Template for Order Confirmation Email</title>
    <!-- Start Common CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {{
            padding: 0;
        }}
        body {{
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }}
        .ExternalClass {{
            width: 100%;
        }}
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {{
                line-height: 100%;
            }}
        .backgroundTable {{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
        }}
        .main-temp table {{
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        }}
            .main-temp table td {{
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }}
    </style>
    <!-- End Common CSS -->
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="backgroundTable main-temp" style="background-color: #d5d5d5;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- Start header Section -->
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 30px;">
                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; text-align: center;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                    <a href="http://localhost:7169/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Walk In Style" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    3828 Mall Road
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    123 Consectetur at ligula 10660
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    Phone: 010-020-0340 | Email:  info@company.com
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                                                    <strong>Order Number:</strong> --OrderId-- | <strong>Order Date:</strong> --OrderDate--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- End header Section -->
                            <!-- Start address Section -->
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 0;">
                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                    Delivery Adderss
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                                    Billing Address
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    --Name--
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    --Name--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    --Address--
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    --Address--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 55%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                    --City--
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 45%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                    --City--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- End address Section -->
                            <!-- Start product Section -->
                            <!-- Start calculation Section -->
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 0;">
                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb; margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td rowspan="5" style="width: 55%;"></td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666;">
                                                    Sub-Total:
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; width: 130px; text-align: right;">
                                                    --SubTotal--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                                    Shipping Fee:
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; text-align: right;">
                                                    $5.00
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-top: 10px;">
                                                    Order Total
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; color: #666666; padding-top: 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    --Total--
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

Here is the e-mail method. Since I am trying to send email from API I had to change the path of the image.
private async Task SendOrderConfirmationEmail(OrderHeaderDTO orderHeaderDTO)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the order for details in the template
        var orders = await _orderRepository.GetOrdersByUser(orderHeaderDTO.UserId);
        var order = orders.Where(o => o.OrderHeader.Id == orderHeaderDTO.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        // Construct the path to the file
        var pathToFile = Path.Combine("Templates", "EmailTemplate", "Confirmation_EmailTemplate.html");

        // Check if the file exists
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathToFile))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The email template file was not found.", pathToFile);
        }
        var builder = new BodyBuilder();
        using (var SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToFile))
        {
            builder.HtmlBody = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var tableRows = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var detail in order.OrderDetails)
        {
            var imageUrl = $"http://localhost:7253/{detail.Product?.ImageUrls.FirstOrDefault()}";
            tableRows.Append($@"
            <tr>
                <td style='padding-top: 0;'>
                    <table width='560' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='devicewidthinner' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan='4' style='padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;'>
                                    <img style='height: 80px;' src='{imageUrl}' alt='Product Image' />
                                </td>
                                <td colspan='2' style='font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-bottom: 5px;'>
                                    {detail.ProductName}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; width: 440px;'>
                                    Quantity: {detail.Count}
                                </td>
                                <td style='width: 130px;'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575;'>
                                    Color: {detail.Product?.Color}
                                </td>
                                <td style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; text-align: right;'>
                                    {detail.Price.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Per Unit
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; padding-bottom: 10px;'>
                                    Size: {detail.Size}
                                </td>
                                <td style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #757575; text-align: right; padding-bottom: 10px;'>
                                    <b style='color: #666666;'>{(detail.Price * detail.Count).ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}</b> Total
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>");
        }

        // Replace the placeholder in the HTML template with the generated tableRows
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("<!-- Start product Section -->", tableRows.ToString());
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--OrderId--", orderHeaderDTO.Id.ToString());
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--OrderDate--", orderHeaderDTO.OrderDate.ToString());
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--Name--", orderHeaderDTO.Name);
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--Address--", orderHeaderDTO.StreetAddress);
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--City--", orderHeaderDTO.City);
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--SubTotal--", orderHeaderDTO.OrderTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--Total--", (orderHeaderDTO.OrderTotal
            + 5).ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        // Add the logo to the email
        var logoPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", "images", "Logo.png");
        var logo = builder.LinkedResources.Add(logoPath.Replace("API", "Server"));
        logo.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
        builder.HtmlBody = builder.HtmlBody.Replace("--Logo--", string.Format(@"<img src='cid:{0}' alt='Walk In Style' />", logo.ContentId));

        // Send the email
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(orderHeaderDTO.Email, "Order Confirmation", builder.HtmlBody);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}

Here is the how I send:
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
{
    try
    {
        var emailToSend = new MimeMessage();
        emailToSend.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("test@test.com"));
        emailToSend.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(email));
        emailToSend.Subject = subject;
        emailToSend.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) { Text = htmlMessage };
        //send email
        using var emailClient = new SmtpClient();
        await emailClient.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync("test@test.com", "test");
        await emailClient.SendAsync(emailToSend);
        await emailClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

There is no error but there is no image in the email either.
I also tried to use image url (http://localhost:7253/images/Logo.png) but it did not display.

You definitely can't provide the image URL with your localhost: "http://localhost:7253/". It is your PC only and outsiders cannot access the URL. Your image needs to be placed in the public (cloud) storage. Unless you need to additional step to convert the image into a base64 string. This will allow the images to be shown without the URL.

note that gmail doesn't allow base64 resources. in our case we upload the images in our public server and put them as img src.

@YongShun, is there a solution for both Gmail, yahoo, outlook etc?

As Peko mentioned Base64 not working, then you should try to place your image in the cloud storage/server.

@YongShun When I deploy my application to the cloud, using the image URL will work for Gmail, yahoo, outlook, etc? I just want to test it before deploying and as far as I understand there is no one solution for all.

You need to upload your image to some sort of cloud storage provider. This could be AWS S3, Azure Blob storage or a free provider. Once uploaded you'll have an internet accessible image and URL that you can use in your email tempalte for the image and will work with ALL email providers.

@Peppermintology Is cloud storage different from Cloud Server where I deploy my web application on IIS?

They are both cloud concepts but they are not the same. You could save your images to the same server as your application as long as the location is publically accessible, and this is a simple solution. However, separating your storage and compute has benefits.

@Peppermintology If I take the easy solution, how can I make images publicly in my cloud server? And how can I match/fetch the required image and use it in my email sending method?

About hosting image resources in IIS and make the image accessible via url -> could you pls help check whether this case helped?

If you have a server, you can upload the image to your server first and link the image from your server.
If you don't have a server, you should look at embedding the picture in the email and referencing it that way. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30126266/2255454
